# Как исправить скрипт, чтобы он работал динамически?

Tags: javascript

Есть отдельный блок из чекбоксов и отдельный блок с таблицей с радио кнопками.

Нужно:

- при клике на первый чекбокс выделялась первую строку в tboby,
  переключить чекбокс и у него поменять фон(добавился класс bg);
- при клике на второй выделилась вторая строка и т.д.

Cкрипт написала, но для каждого элемента

```
$('#checkbox').on('click', function () {
  $('tbody tr:nth-child(1)').toggleClass('active');
  $('.toggle-bg').toggleClass('bg');
});
$('#checkbox1').on('click', function () {
  $('tbody tr:nth-child(2)').toggleClass('active');
});
$('#checkbox2').on('click', function () {
  $('tbody tr:nth-child(3)').toggleClass('active');
});
```

не получилось с радио кнопкой. Можете помочь и объяснить как правильнее сделать. Благодарна за любую помощь.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/YulyaYulya/r7acbk45/16/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// вешаем событие на все input type="checkbox"
$('[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function (evt) {
    let checkbox = $(evt.target),
        // берём индекс чекбокса  
        index = checkbox.closest('div.checkbox').index(),
        // находим tr в таблице с таким же индексом
        row = $('tbody tr')[index];
  // добавляем найденной tr класс
  $(row).toggleClass('active');
  // внутри tr ищем эл-т с классом toggle-bg 
  // и добавляем/удаляем у него класс bg
  $(row).find('.toggle-bg').toggleClass('bg');
  // для input value = on меняем свойство checked
  // в зависимости от данного свойства у нажатого чекбокса
  $(row).find('[type="radio"][value="on"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
  // для input value = off меняем свойство checked
  // в зависимости от данного свойства у нажатого чекбокса
  $(row).find('[type="radio"][value="off"]').prop('checked', !this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Там в вопросе вроде что-то про радио-кнопку.

Comment: @Igor исправил. Подумал там с классом что-то не то было

Comment: Отдельно спасибо за комментарии в коде. Еще многому мне учиться.